# Assign Macro to excel combobox

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# console program that creates a combobox in an excel file that has already been made (the c# program as a connection to it).
Now I want to assign a Macro (that was already made in the excel) to the combobox (but since the combobox only shows in the excel later I can't assign it to the macro.

Is it possible? If yes can you guide me through it?

Thank You.

//It defines the text of the options available inside the combobox

```
Sub Selection()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 1")).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "Sheet1!$A$3:$A$9"
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .DropDownLines = 8
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
End Sub
```

//This creates the dropbox inside the excel that has already the code posted first

```
 Excel.Range RangeDrop = datosFinal.get_Range("B2", "B2");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
    xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns(endSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
    xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)Range.Left, (double)Range.Top,(double)Range.Width, (double)Range.Height, true);
    xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)RangeDrop.Left, (double)RangeDrop.Top, 90, 30,true);
```

Comment: what sort of combobox are we talking about here? Is it an ActiveX or Forms? Is it embed in Excel from C#? How

Comment: Forms, Yes it's C# console program that creates it inside the excel.

Comment: can you share an SSCCE with us??

Comment: SSCCE?
Macro has this pseudo code
     Sub Selection()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Drop Down 1")).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "Sheet1!$A$3:$A$9"
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .DropDownLines = 8
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
End Sub

It defines the text of the options available inside the combobox
-------------

Comment: Excel.Range RangeDrop = datosFinal.get_Range("B2", "B2");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns xlDropDowns;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDown xlDropDown;
xlDropDowns = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DropDowns)(endSheet.DropDowns(Type.Missing)));
xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)Range.Left, (double)Range.Top, (double)Range.Width, (double)Range.Height, true);
xlDropDown = xlDropDowns.Add((double)RangeDrop.Left, (double)RangeDrop.Top, 90, 30, true);

//This creates the dropbox inside the excel that has already the code posted first

PS: I can't format this into readable comment

Comment: please edit your question and add the code to it